# Is it possible to partially accept an edit?

Tags: support, editing, review

A post of mine just got edited. Most of the edit was great. Just one thing was not true. Is there a way to partially accept an edit. I just accepted and then edited the edit, is there a better way?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can choose to *improve* the edit.

You get into the regular edit mask, when you are finished you have two choices:

- keep  "the suggestion was helpful" checked - in that case the suggestion is approved immediately and the post is saved with the suggested **and** your edits
- uncheck "helpful" - in that case the suggestion is rejected immediately, but the post is also saved withe the remaining suggests **and** your edits

So if you "improve" the post you determine

- how it looks in the end
- if the suggestor is awarded the 2 points rep

Comment: I will try this next time. I don't have rights to review edits normally so I can only check when someone edits one of my answers.